# What could be the reason for this CloudFormation to stall during deployment?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have the following cloudformation nested stack structure:

- **master**

  - **VPC** (CREATE_COMPLETE)
  - **Security Groups** (CREATE_COMPLETE)
  - **...** (CREATE_COMPLETE)
  - ECS (CREATE_COMPLETE)
  - **Service** (eventually CREATE_FAILED - Service [ARN] did not stabilize.)

    - **ALB** (CREATE_COMPLETE)

      - **Certificate Manager** (CREATE_COMPLETE)

Service nests the ALB stack which nests the SSL Cert stack. They are a dependency chain.

For some reason even though the certificate manager and alb stacks both complete successfully, the service doesn't continue past where the ALB stack is called. Instead it remains stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS without any errors until it times out. When it finally does time out it gives a 'service [arn] failed to stabilize' error. Why would this be? There were no errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECS cluster created and completed without error in CloudFormation, but it turns out that there actually was an error in ECS: the containers weren't being added to the cluster and that caused the services stack to hang. If ECS is in the mix of a CloudFormation nested stack, be sure to check the ECS logs.

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-certificatemanager-certificate.html:

*Important
When you use the AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate resource in an AWS CloudFormation stack, the stack will remain in the CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state and any further stack operations will be delayed until you act upon the instructions in the certificate validation email.*

Is this the problem?

Comment: No, I have automated verification for the certificates stack. That stack was CREATE_COMPLETE. Turns out the issue was in ECS. The containers weren't being added to the cluster and that log item from ECS wasn't being passed through to CloudFormation

Comment: how have you automated the verification for the certificates stack?